# How do i get parameter content of console

Tags: javascript, ajax, parameters, console.log, console.dir

I have a form populated by ajax, and for manipulation of the frontend, I'm trying to something happen when the div has content, but I can't see the content of the div...only with the console.dir, like the picture, so my questions is how do I console.dir only one parameter (says innerTEXT)?

[image]

```js
   var abc = document.getElementById('p1tipo');
   console.dir(abc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <span id="p1tipo">something AJAX</dd>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `console.dir(abc.innerText);` ?

Comment: @Gavin yes i did but with no success...